# Can I word-break at a specific character with react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, line-breaks

I'm using react native to create a category table.
Is there any way I can make the characters(texts) inside the table to line break at after or before a specific character?

for example : apple/banana/avocado

I want it to render like this (line break at after 'slashes') :
apple/banana/</ br>avocado

Thanks,

Comment: The `<br/>` tag doesnt exist in react native so you'll probably just be using `'\n'`. So you may be able to get all with just using replaceAll instead of map, e.g `'apple/banana/avocado'.replaceAll('/','\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Like in a normal react application you can use the following javascript functions:

- Split your string on each "/", example:

> var elements = yuourString.split(/\//)

- Then you can use Map to render an object for each element, example:

> elements.map(x => <SomeReactNativeComponent />);

Answer (score 0):

You could take match instead of split by taking some non breaking character, a breaking character and other non breking character.

```js
const names='banana/apple/mango/grapes';
const result=names.match(/([A-z]+\/[A-z]+)/g);
console.log(result)
```

After breaking the names into an array you can simply map them in react native

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/E-V028fIS):

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

const string = 'apple/banana/avocado';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
        Before Change:{'\n '} {string}
      </Text>
      <Text style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
        After Change:{'\n '} {string.replaceAll('/', '\n  ')}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  
});
```

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/Nld10APw9

Comment: If you are working with react-native-paper `DataTable.Cell` doesnt do multiline so you have to resort to using a View instead. I also switch to `string.split('/').map(v=><Text>{v}</Text>` in case you actually needed to map over values